# Software to stream mp3 files playlist in mp3 format

Tags: streaming, filestream, internet-radio

I need a software to stream mp3 files and give me API or something that I can use it to show which track is now being played. Actually I have create an Online Radio with offline file source and showing playlist in frontend or player.

I've tried **Windows media Encoder**, **Microsoft Expressions Encoder** and **IceCast** and no one of them does what I need.

Is there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IceCast + ezStream did the job.